# Yeoman dependencies for AngularJS project

Tags: compass

Using Yeoman and the AngularJS generator I could previously follow their tutorial and install all the necessary packages and tools (bower, gulp, grunt,...) to get up and running.  Per their website:

```
npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp
```

then added the angularJS project 'generator':

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

created a folder locally, and run

```
yo angular
```

in that folder in order to prepare a sample AngularJS project with all the necessary tools and scaffolding generated by Yeoman.

The command:

```
grunt serve
```

Launched the sample application successfully, allowing me to start learning about AngularJS (which I'm very new to).

The problem: I have repeated these steps again, (3 months later), and, admittedly, I have potentially taken on updates to some of the installed packages.

Now, when I create a new project and invoke 'grunt serve' I get:

```
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "compass.bat --versio
n"
'compass.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
     Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

and the site does not launch...

Researching this problem, some responses say that I now need to install yet another tool - Ruby, followed by the 'compass' gem.

Is this really necessary ??  (I'm hesitant because the Yeoman website does not require this to get started using the angular generator).

Is there perhaps another solution ?

thanks

Comment: check whether u have ruby or not by ruby -v

Comment: I don't have ruby. my point, however, is that I *never* had ruby installed, and, this used to work.

Comment: may they would have node module for sass. check the dependencies in package.json

Comment: on package.json, there is this child under "devDependencies": {
...
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.0",
...
}

which the previous angular project's package.json, does not have.

I'm assuming this is related...

Comment: yes add it. do npm update --save

Comment: still no luck. failed again with: 

'Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "compass.bat --versio
n"
'compass.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.'

in fact, compass.bat does not exist in project folder.

Comment: have you installed the compass globally !

Comment: yes, I did execute 

npm install grunt-contrib-compass -g

is that what you meant ?

Comment: Try this commands gem install compass, cd <myproject>, compass install compass

Comment: I don't have Ruby installed. To use 'gem', in would need Rubt installed no?  My original question was to confirm if Ruby is required in order to use Yeoman. It feels like we have gone full circle, and, it seems there is no alternative. The angular generator requires Ruby due to its dependancy on compass. That seems like the conclusion wouldn't you agree ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like compass is necessary by default.

It also seems that the only solution here is to go ahead and download Ruby (if you do not already have it), in order to install compass.  These instructions cover how:

1. Download Ruby here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and install.
2. Install the compass library: `gem install compass`

Answer (score 0):

Yes compass is necessary.
Download and install ruby http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

and run ***gem install compass*** in ruby command prompt to install compass.

now it will work!!!.